# Garbage Disposal Electrical Connection

Tags: electrical, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

I'm swapping the old garbage disposal at my wife and I's first home.  I disconnected the electrical components, but I'm stuck on how to remove this power cord.  I doubt it any of these parts came with the old disposal. It's on there ridiculously tight and the only grip I can get on it is the bottom part, but I feel like the top part needs to be removed as well.  Any thoughts?  I don't have much slack, so this is the best vantage point I have.  I have some gut feelings, but I don't want to damage anything.  I feel like I'm stuck in a holding pattern at this point.

[image: How do I remove this?]

[image: inside of the unit]

UPDATE: the internet is amazing! Thank you both, that was exactly the confirmation I needed!

Answer (score 5):

The round hole/port where the conduit fitting is located is actually a threaded port.
If you unscrew the locking nut on the fitting, you will then be able to unscrew the threaded conduit fitting from the threaded port.

Threaded port:

[image]

Seal-tite conduit connector:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need two tools. One must be a wrench to fit the bottom part, and be thin enough to let the top part project past it. The other must be a pipe wrench, vice-grip pliers, or adjustable pliers, to grip the top part. Don't be afraid to use a lot of force. Try to keep your fingers out of the way when the tools slip, or when the parts suddenly loosen and separate.